# My askQuestion() function in Javascript is always marking the answeras wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The link to my pen in CodePen - http://codepen.io/PartTimeCoder/pen/WwMxEX?editors=0010

The Javascript is here:

```
function randomNum(digits) {
    return Math.floor(Math.pow(10, digits - 1) + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, digits - 1));
}

function askQuestion(digits) {
    $(".result").html("");

    var factor1 = randomNum(digits);
    var factor2 = randomNum(digits);
    var correctanswer = factor1 * factor2;
    var answer = parseInt($(".answer").val(), 10);

    console.log(correctanswer);

    $(".question").html(factor1 + " × " + factor2);

    var score = 0;

    //Problem Starts Here
    $(".check").click(function() {
        if (correctanswer == answer) {
            $(".result").html("Correct");
            score += 1;
            $(".score").html(score);
            askQuestion(digits);
        } else {
            $(".result").html("Wrong");
            score -= 1;
            $(".score").html(score);
        }
    });
    //Problem Ends Here
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".answer").hide();
    $(".check").hide();

    var digits = 0;

    $(".digits-1").click(function() {
        digits += 1;
    });

    $(".digits-2").click(function() {
        digits += 2;
    });

    $(".digits-3").click(function() {
        digits += 3;
    });

    $(".btn").click(function() {
        $(".btn").hide();
        $(".answer").show();
        $(".check").show();
        askQuestion(digits);
    });
});
```

In between the comments is where I think the problem is. For example when it asks 4 x 9 and i input 36, it still marks it as wrong. I don't know why this is doing this. At first I though that the inputted information might still be a string so I used parseInt on it and it still didn't work. All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're caching the initial value of the `$('.answer')` element in your `answer` variable. When you do `$('.answer').val()`, it saves what is there **at that time**, so if the user changes their answer afterwards, it won't be reflected in your variable. What you want to do is something like this:

```
// Rest of your code above
var answer = $(".answer");

console.log(correctanswer);

$(".question").html(factor1 + " × " + factor2);

var score = 0;

//Problem Starts Here
$(".check").click(function() {
    // Don't check what is in the input until you're ready to use the value.
    if (correctanswer == parseInt(answer.val(), 10)) {
        $(".result").html("Correct");
        score += 1;
        $(".score").html(score);
        askQuestion(digits);
    } else {
        $(".result").html("Wrong");
        score -= 1;
        $(".score").html(score);
    }
});
```

Comment: That works but another thing that I just noticed after this, if you get a question right the first time it will add to the score, but the second time it won't. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Your `score` variable is set to 0 every time you enter the askQuestion function. Therefore, they'll never get more than 1. You can either move that variable outside the function, or you can read from the `$('.score')` element's value.

Comment: Also, get your check click event out of the addQuestion function. Otherwise, every time you call that function, you'll add another listener and you'll see the score rise at a ridiculous rate.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

The click handler has a reference to the old answer value. You must get the value from the input everytime. Something like this:

```
$(".check").click(function() {
    var answer = parseInt($(".answer").val(), 10);
    if (correctanswer == answer) {
        $(".result").html("Correct");
        score += 1;
        $(".score").html(score);
        askQuestion(digits);
    } else {
        $(".result").html("Wrong");
        score -= 1;
        $(".score").html(score);
    }
});
```